# Задание времени для UILocalNotification используя UIStepper и UISwitch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Необходимо отправлять напоминания раз в сутки, по установленному времени. Время устанавливаю в формате от 0 до 23 часов при использовании UIStepper и UISwitch. Приходит по два одинаковых уведомления в одно время, проверил брэйкпоинтом, но повторений setEveryDayNotification не нашел...

```
var hour = 0.0
var remindOnOff = false
let notification = UILocalNotification()
@IBOutlet weak var remindStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var remindLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var remindSwitch: UISwitch!
```

Во viewDidLoad()

```
    remindStepper.wraps = true
    remindStepper.value = hour
    remindStepper.minimumValue = 0
    remindStepper.maximumValue = 23
    //ЧТЕНИЕ УСТАНОВЛЕННОГО ВРЕМЕНИ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("hour") != nil  { hour = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("hour") as! Double }
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("remindOnOff") != nil  { remindOnOff = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("remindOnOff") as! Bool }
    if remindOnOff == true {
        remindSwitch.on = true
    } else {
        remindSwitch.on = false
    }
    remindLabel.text = "\(Int(hour)):00"
```

Создаем уведомление

```
    func setEveryDayNotification(date:NSDate){

    for index in 0...365 {
        let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertTitle = "GuyFit"
        notification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString("Reminder of the workout", comment:"")
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString("Go to GuyFit", comment:"")
        notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        notification.fireDate = date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(index*60*60*24))
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

Задаем значение времени

```
@IBAction func remindStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Int(sender.value), forKey: "hour")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    remindLabel.text = "\(String(format: "%.0f", arguments: [sender.value])):00"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    remindOnOff = false
    remindSwitch.on = false
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(remindOnOff, forKey: "remindOnOff")
}
```

Включаем и выключаем уведомления

```
    @IBAction func remindSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
    if remindSwitch.on {
        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound], categories: [])
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        let date:NSDate = NSDate()
        let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: date)
        components.hour = Int(remindStepper.value)
        var time:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
        if(time.compare(date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) {
            time = time.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24)
        }
        self.setEveryDayNotification(time)

        remindOnOff = true
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(remindOnOff, forKey: "remindOnOff")
    } else {
        remindOnOff = false
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(remindOnOff, forKey: "remindOnOff")
    }

}
```

Comment: можно подробнее. то есть вам надо, когда пользователь нажал на кнопку, прочитать что в remindLabel и запустить, например, 10 уведомлений на следующие 10 дней в то время, которое было в label?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы каждый день, в то время которое в лэйбле установил пользователь, приходило оповещение

Comment: другими словами, вам надо установленное время сконвертировать в NSDate, и потом в цикле запускать локальные уведомления каждый раз прибавляя к дате 86400 (количество секунд в сутках)

Comment: А как это реализовать? Мне не хватает знаний

Comment: remindStepper это изменение значения? видимо тогда еще есть кнопка чтоб запустить весь механизм оповещения?

Comment: Да степпер меняет значение и в айбиэкшин нужно вставить функцию sendNotification()  для активации оповещения, это значение наверное должно сохраняться в юзердефолтс, а при значении off механизм оповещения должен быть отключен. Я думаю так должно быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример того, как это можно реализовать - скопируйте в пустой проект и запустите

создает оповещения на 365 дней вперед в заданное время (час)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var label:UILabel!
    var stepper:UIStepper!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        stepper = UIStepper(frame: CGRectMake(0,100,200,100))
        stepper.minimumValue = 0
        stepper.maximumValue = 23
        stepper.addTarget(self, action: "stepperChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(stepper)

        label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,200,200,100))
        label.text = "0"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,300,200,100))
        button.setTitle("schedule", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "startAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func stepperChanged(sender:UIStepper) {
        label.text = String(format: "%.0f", arguments: [sender.value])
    }

    func startAction(sender:UIButton) {

        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound], categories: [])
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        let date:NSDate = NSDate()

        let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: date)
        components.hour = Int(stepper.value)

        var time:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!

        if(time.compare(date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) {
            time = time.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24)
        }
        self.setEveryDayNotification(time)
    }

    func setEveryDayNotification(date:NSDate){

        let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

        notification.alertTitle = "alert title"
        notification.alertBody = "alert body"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.alertAction = "Run the workout"
        notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        notification.fireDate = date
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: Максим, у меня почему то при запуске на девайсе приходит по два одинаковых уведомления в одно время? Что не так?

Comment: поставьте брейкпоинт в `setEveryDayNotification` посмотрите, может он вызывается дважды

Comment: проверил брэйкпоинтом, но повторений setEveryDayNotification не нашел... код выше отредактировал

Comment: Тестирую дальше, оказывается на вторые сутки приходит два уведомления, на третьи сутки три уведомления и тд...

Comment: Максим подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить

Comment: ну скидывайте весь код, будем смотреть

Comment: Весь код отредактировал в начале страницы вопроса

Comment: Кстати ваш код тоже добавил в отдельный проект и при запуске уведомления так же приходят как и в моем проекте

Comment: сейчас посмотрю у себя

Comment: for не нужен - не заметил, что там стоит `repeatInterval`. исправил ответ